# Outlook interoop. oSelection after few attempts starts to return old selection items

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook, ms-office

I have this code where I access outlook explorer to fetch selected items. First time I access it it returns one email, now if I go to outlook and select older email it returns already two emails instead of only one. And if I go further and select new items (not multiselect just simple single select) they begin to stack up.

Code here:

```
public IEnumerable<MailItemVM> GetSelectedMailItem()
        {
            RetrieveOutlookProcessHandle(false);

            List<MailItemVM> result = new List<MailItemVM>();

            //olApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            //KillOlProcess = true;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer oExplorer = olApp.ActiveExplorer();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Selection oSelection = oExplorer.Selection;

            foreach (object item in oSelection)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mi = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)item;

                if (mi != null)
                {
                    MailItemVM mVM = new MailItemVM()
                    {
                        Title = mi.Subject,
                        Description = mi.BodyFormat == Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML ? mi.HTMLBody : mi.Body
                    };
                    result.Add(mVM);
                }
                break;

            }

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(olApp);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oExplorer);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oSelection);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(olNS);

            var olProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").FirstOrDefault();

            olApp = null;
            olNS = null;

            if (KillOlProcess && olProcess != null)
            {
                olProcess.Kill();
            }

            return result;
        }

private void RetrieveOutlookProcessHandle(bool forceNewApp)
        {
            // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
            if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
            {
                // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
                olApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
                KillOlProcess = false;
            }
            else if (!forceNewApp)
            {
                // If not, create a new instance of Outlook and log on to the default profile.
                olApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                KillOlProcess = true;
            }
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Outlook must be running or invalid state");

            olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds suspiciously like this issue:

Outlook, custom task pane and drag-drop problem: C#, VB.NET
http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/03/26/outlook-task-pane-drag-drop/

Since you're not doing custom drag/drop, I believe the culprit may be unreleased references to the MailItem objects.  I would refactor away from the foreach and use a for count, as foreach calls are bad news in Outlook when iterating collections.

But most important: Call ReleaseComObject on each item after you are finished with it.

Comment: The foreach is a very good thought my friend, also oSelection variable should be dynamic and accessed as collection through it. Moreover, I was doing custom drag drop. Yet, I was doing it in WPF not in winforms and found a faster solution... Release com objects on each drag leave or drop without custom droptargets. As guys in MS probably solved that issue in dragover event getting IDataObject ref. Thank you a lot for pointing me to the right direction!